# Lattice automorphisms of a countable product of copies of ${\mathbb N}$

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

For an integer $r\geq 1$, one can equip ${\mathbb N}^r$ with the product lattice structure  defined by $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r) \leq  (y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_r)$ iff $x_k\leq y_k$ for every $k$. Similarly for ${\mathbb N}^{(\infty)}$, the set of all nonnegative integer sequences that are eventually zero (which can be viewed as the union of all the ${\mathbb N}^r$).

If $\sigma$ is any permutation of ${\mathbb N}^*$, the map
$(x_1,x_2,\ldots) \mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\ldots)$ defines a lattice automorphism (i.e. an order-preserving bijection) of ${\mathbb N}^{(\infty)}$.

Are there other automorphisms of ${\mathbb N}^{(\infty)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Every automorphism of a lattice permutes its [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(order_theory)), which here are the elements $(e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$. And an automorphism of $\mathbb{N}^{(\infty)}$ is completely determined by how it permutes atoms, because every element can be defined order-theoretically starting from the atoms in terms of covering. I don't know a clean way to describe the full induction but e.g. $(2, 0, 0, \dots)$ is the unique element which covers $e_1$ but does not cover $e_2, e_3, \dots$, and $(2, 1, 0, \dots)$ is the unique element which covers the previous element but doesn't cover $(0, 2, 0, \dots), e_3, \dots$ and so forth. Generally we can induct on $\sum x_i$ to show that each element in a given degree is completely determined by how it covers elements of the previous degree.

Comment: I think this argument generalizes to some portion of the full product $\mathbb{N}^{\infty}$ but I'm not sure how much of it; I think I can get the bounded sequences but I'm not sure about the unbounded ones.

Comment: The result works for $\mathbb N^\infty$ too. The key point is that the $k$-th component $x_k$ of an infinite sequence $x$ is the number of elements $y\leq x$ that are above $e_k$ and no other atoms.

Comment: Ah, that's much nicer than what I had in mind, that gives a cleaner solution to the original too!